# UDF to calculate a score - Input is scored on predefined parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a SQL Server User Defined Function (UDF) which calculates a score and applies the function during the table creation process.

The table has the following columns:

```
MemberID(PK)
Gender 
Name
DOB
Weight
Height
SmokingHabit
Salary
CalculatedScore
```

The calculated score is calculated from the sum of each individual score below

Parameters

**Age**

- If the age is between 20-30 score is 5
- If the age is between 31-40 score is 4
- If the age is between 41-50 score is 3
- If the age is >50 score is 2

**Weight(kg) / Height(m)**

- If it is between 20-25 score is 1
- If it is between 25-30 score is 3
- If it is between 30-35 score is 5
- If it is between 35-40 score is 2

**Smoker**

- If smoker status is YES score is 0
- If smoker status is NO score is 5

**Salary**

- If salary is less than $50k score is 1
- If salary is 50k-60k score is 2
- If salary is 60k-70k score is 3
- If salary is greater than 70k score is 4

I'm at a complete loss as to how to code this, I had started with this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FCupid]
( 
    @gender YES/NO, 
    @name varchar(15), 
    @dob datetime, 
    @weight int, 
    @height int, 
    @smoker Yes/NO, 
    @salary int
)

RETURNS @Member table
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT @Member ( @gender, @name, @dob, @weight, @height, @smoker, @salary)
    SELECT m.gender, m.dob, m.weight, m.height, m.smoker, m.salary,
```

And then I struggle.

Any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: I take it this is MS SQL and not MySQL as tagged? Also your `YES/NO` data type for the `@gender` and `@smoker` parameters, are these `bit` data types?

Comment: Why does this function return a **table** if you're only passing in a single set of parameters? Shouldn't this just return the score as an `INT` ??

Comment: @kev yes, that was a mistake. And yes again they are bit data types.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that just returns the **score** as an `INT` as something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FCupid]
   (@gender CHAR(1), @name varchar(15), @dob datetime, 
    @weight int, @height int, @smoker BIT, @salary int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Score INT

    -- determine age in years    
    DECLARE @Age INT
    SELECT @Age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dob, GETDATE())

    SELECT 
        @Score = CASE 
                    WHEN @Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 5
                    WHEN @Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 4
                    WHEN @Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 3
                    WHEN @Age > 50 THEN 2
                    ELSE 0
                END

    -- determine weight/height ratio - this should be **DECIMAL**, though - not INT !!      
    DECLARE @WeightHeight INT

    SET @WeightHeight = @Weight / @height

    SET 
       @Score = @Score + 
                CASE 
                  -- what if that ratio is **below** 20 ???
                  WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 20 AND 25 THEN 1
                  WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN 3
                  WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 5
                  WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 35 AND 40 THEN 2
                  ELSE 0  
                END

    -- add five points if non-smoker    
    IF @Smoker = 0
        SET @Score = @Score + 5

    -- determine score by salary    
    SET 
       @Score = @Score + 
                CASE 
                   WHEN @Salary < 50000 THEN 1
                   WHEN @Salary BETWEEN 50001 AND 60000 THEN 2
                   WHEN @Salary BETWEEN 60001 AND 70000 THEN 3
                   WHEN @Salary > 70000 THEN 4
                END


    RETURN @Score
END
```

That way, you can call this function with all the values at hand, and have it determine the `Score` that you can then use to insert into a table as needed

Also as a side-note: I think weight and height should be `DECIMAL(10,2)` or something like that - not `INT`. How would you express a height of 1.86m with just an `INT` ?? 1? or 2? And the `CASE` statement for that ratio should also handle cases where it's value is below 20, or over 40 - even if it's just using 0 for the score in that case (but it should be clearly defined).

**Update:** if you want to insert data into a table, you could use this function like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Name, Gender, DateOfBirth, ...., Score)
   SELECT
       @Name, @Gender, @dob, .....,
       dbo.FCupid(@Gender, @Name, @dob, .........)
```

So basically, you can call this function in a `SELECT` as if it were a column (more or less)

Comment: Hey there thanks heaps for the reply it is very helpful. I am just wondering how i utilise this function once the score is found and insert all the values and the score into the table? I am quite new to this, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way for an input like this to calculate the score automatically ?

INSERT INTO Member_Profile(Gender, Name, dob, Weight, Height, Smoker, Salary)
VALUES
(1, 'James', '19841230', 59, 185, 0, 80000),
(1, 'Jack', '19700430', 75, 182, 1, 95000),
(1, 'James', '19670721', 60, 167, 0, 75000);
GO

Comment: @JohnSmith: if you want to use the `VALUES(....)` approach, you have to call the function **before** the `INSERT`  and store the returned value into a variable